# Путь к файлам внутри jar

Tags: java, файлы, maven, jar, сборка

Проблема в следующем, имеются properties файлы которые лежат в resources, естественно пути указаны

```
src/main/resources/number.properties
```

Но когда собираю с помощью maven все в один jar пути сбиваются и файлы становятся недоступны. Есть ли способ обращаться к файлам внутри jar или легче по другому настроить сборку.

```xml
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
        <finalName>textred</finalName>
        <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>org.prog.textred.init.Run</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>build-jar-with-dependencies</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: покажите как вы обращаетесь к файлу в коде?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема разрешилась самым простым путем

```
ReadBase.class.getResourceAsStream(path);
```

Где path - это путь к файлу